# How to identify a LDAP packet/frame

Tags: networking, ip, tcp, ldap, packet

I'm developing an application in Java which needs to know if a frame contains a LDAP packet or not.
 So far, I've figured out how to find out if the frame contains IPv4 and TCP headers but how do I check for LDAP?
 On researching online I cannot find any clear identifier for the LDAP header
Thanks

Comment: You won't be able to tell with just a frame. With a complete packet you would see something like [LDIF](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2849) as the content. You would have to check for that format. There likely isn't going to be any magic number or similar as you're on the application level.

Comment: Do you know if these frame use the standard LDAP port? Standard LDAP port is 384: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: @NathanShiraini No, I'm using port 3060 for my personal testing. I originally thought to program my code to look for port 3060 or 384 and then assume that if the port matches, it's an LDAP frame but isn't it ill advised to assume all traffic on this port will strictly be LDAP?

Comment: That depends on your application. If you are just making a small logger, matching the IP/port pair to a list of known LDAP services should do. If you are designing a packet-analysing firewall, obviously you will have to use a better strategy, like the one recommended by @Seth.